# Is possible to access BT Hub from local network (behind another router) or remotely?

Tags: router

Setup:
Internet access point: BT Business Hub 5 -> office router/firewall (draytek vigor 2830 router with build in firewall, standard setup) -> local network
Problem:
Access to BT Hub from local network or remotely?

I need to get access to bt hub from local network. But hub isn't main router only working as some kind of modem only. I search online but can't find any solutions. I have all logins etc. I know how to access bt hub when computer is connected to it but can't find way to access it from my network. Does anyone try to do this?

Comment: Please provide the configurations of your hub, router, and firewall. Otherwise we’re just guessing.

Comment: I don't think the BT hub can work in bridge mode, so it must be acting as a router?  What network (subnet) are you using on the WAN (BT Hub) side of the Draytek, and what network (subnet) are you using on the LAN side of the Draytek?  Does the Draytek perform NAT?  Maybe you are not NATing correctly for the BT Hub IP, which is 192.168.1.254 by default.  Have you tried connecting to that address from the LAN?

Comment: Can you provide a diagram with physical topology and network addressing?